# Power BI desktop connecting to data source with different user name than the one I am logged in as

Tags: sql-server, authentication, powerbi, connection, authorization

When connecting to SQL Server Data Source for getting data, it uses my windows authentication by default, and based on the screen, it seems that there is no way to change this.

[image: screenshot]

What if I had a different account meant for reports with SQL Server authentication that had r/o access to specific tables only for reporting -- does Power BI allow me to connect with SQL Server authentication in a different way? Or maybe I want to use windows authentication, but I don't want to use the account I am logged into; I want to use a different one... How about that?

It seems like it knows I have authentication to the database based on who I am logged in as, and it gives me no other option to be able to connect in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

That is because it stored the credentials that you entered earlier. To change or delete the stored credentials, go to `File` -> `Options and settings` -> `Data source settings`. There you will see the data sources used in the currently loaded report (if any) and the global ones used before. Find the data source that you want to change and click `Edit Permissions` button:

[image]

There you can adjust the data source settings, change or delete the stored credentials:

[image]

If you click on the `Edit` button, you will be able to enter new Windows, Database, etc. credentials to be used:

[image]